# Regex to replace tags to make valid html

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to convert the below mentioned tag:

```
[caption id="attachment_812" align="alignleft" width="240"]<img class="wp-
image-92692" src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="316" height="210"/>Sample 
text[/caption]
```

To the one below using regex:

```
<caption id="attachment_812" align="alignleft" width="240"><img class="wp-
image-92692" src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="316" height="210"/>Sample 
text</caption>
```

So basically I am wanting to convert [caption] tag into `<caption>`. So that it becomes a valid html tag and then use html agility pack to parse the tag.

Below is the C# code:

```
//Replace [caption]
htmlSource = Regex.Replace(htmlSource, @"\[caption]", "<caption>");
//Replace [/caption]
htmlSource = Regex.Replace(htmlSource, @"\[/caption]", "</caption>");
```

This works for caption tags that don't have attributes. I am looking for a better solution to even hold the attributes and just replace the square brackets to make it a valid html tag.

Comment: you probably need to escape the closing `]` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(htmlSource, @"\[(\/*caption.*?)\]", @"<$1>")
```

See [Demo](https://regexr.com/3lkt3)

Comment: To have multiple tags extend it like this: `Regex.Replace(htmlSource, @"\[(\/*(caption|img).*?)\]", @"<$1>")`